# Retrieving a value from specific line in StringReader.ReadLine() C#

Tags: c#, winforms

could you please share your thoughts on how a specific line containing text could be retrieved.  I am searching for two values using `.Contains` within a locally stored dynamic html file as my source.

The first value is fine, however the second value is not as easy.  The closest unique/static piece of text is 6 lines above from the needed value.

Here is what I have:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Path\HtmlFile.html");

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(html))
{
    string line;

    do
    {
        line = stringReader.ReadLine();

        if (line != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("'MyFirstUniqueID' :'"))
            {
                int uniqueOneIdStart = line.IndexOf(("ID' :'"), StringComparison.Ordinal) + ("ID' :'").Length;
                int uniqueOneIdEnd = line.IndexOf("'});", uniqueOneIdStart, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                MyFirstUniqueIDList.Add(line.Substring(uniqueOneIdStart, uniqueOneIdEnd - uniqueOneIdStart));
             }

             if (line.Contains("'MySecondUniqueID' :'"))
             {
                 // 6 lines below is the value needed.
                 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                 {
                     var j = stringReader.ReadLine();

                     // the 6th popup window shows my value.
                     MessageBox.Show(j);
                 }
             }
         }

         //File.Delete(@"C:\\Path\HtmlFile.html");
     } while (line != null);
}
```

This is how the html file looks like:

```
'MySecondUniqueID' :'
</td>
<td style="">
Some-dynamic-value&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="">
Finally-HERE-is-the-value-I-need&nbsp;
```

Ideally once I am able to get the value from 6th line on however many records I'd add them to `MySecondUniqueIDList.Add(...)`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
- Thank you, Mark.

Comment: There's not much you can do without changing the source HTML (e.g. tagging the value you actually need). You could also use a full fledged HTML parser, which would be much more reliable (after all, you don't want the sixth line after your tag, you want the third column of the row with a given ID :) ).

Comment: HtmlAgility pack is your friend : http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: 10x to everyone for your attention and responses.  I was able to resolve it by adding an if statement as such:

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
          string j = stringReader.ReadLine();
            
          if (i == 5)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(j.Remove(j.Length-6, 6).Trim());
          }
      }

Answer (score 0):

There is a greate fiature for this job [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)